# relation between ranks of processes after using MPI_COMM_split

Tags: mpi, rank, communicator

I used MPI_Comm_split to split the default MPI communicator.If initially there were 10 processes in default communicator ,MPI_COMM_WORLD and ,say, their ranks were identified by id_original. The new communicator consisted of  4 processes with id_original 6,7,8,9.These processes will have ranks defined by , say , id_new in the new communicator. What will be the relation between ranks of processes in these two communicators. Will the processes with id_original 6,7,8,9 will have new ranks 0,1,2,3 **respectively** in the new communicator or the ordering might be different?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "key" argument to [MPI_Comm_split](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Comm_split.html) to control the order in the new communicator. For example, you could use the rank in MPI_Comm_world (or your "id_original") as the key, like so:

```
MPI_Comm_split( MPI_COMM_WORLD, id_original >= 6 && id_original <= 9,
                id_original, &newComm );
```

Comment: Are you sure? By my testing, any (literally, any at all) `key` argument retains original process ordering (tie's included), even when you try to change the rank ordering! (e.g. by passing `(id_original + x)%size` where `x < size` and `size` is the total number of processes)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node137.html#SECTION00642000000000000000) (emphasis by me):

> Within each subgroup, the processes
>   are ranked in the order defined by the
>   value of the argument key, **with ties
>   broken according to their rank in the
>   old group**.

So yes, if processes 6-9 provide the same value for `key`, then they will get ranks 0-3 in the new communicator, respectively. If this is crucial for the correctness of the program, though, then you should make this arrangement explicit in your code using Edric's method.